# CherryPy authentication timeout

Tags: python, cherrypy

I added digest authentication to my CherryPy server, and I wanted to know on what criteria the users' authentication is revoked and they are prompted to enter credentials again. Deleting cookies doesn't force a prompt, but using Incognito or another browser does.

My config:

```
{ 'tools.auth_digest.on': True,
  'tools.auth_digest.realm': 'localhost',
  'tools.auth_digest.get_ha1': auth_digest.get_ha1_dict_plain(USERS),
  'tools.auth_digest.key': key,
  'tools.auth_digest.accept_charset': 'UTF-8' }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have the proper HTTP response so that the browser clear out the user credentials, basically responding with  `401 Unauthorized` and a challenge in how to authenticate with the `WWW-Authenticate` header.

Here is an implementation using a custom CherryPy tool and a `Cookie` that is used as way to communicate the intention to the browser and the backend (HTTP auth is stateless and we have to go back and forth to deauth and redirect).

```
import cherrypy
from cherrypy.lib import auth_digest


REALM = 'localhost'
KEY = '24684651368351320asd1wdasd'
CHARSET = 'UTF-8'


@cherrypy.tools.register('before_handler')
def with_logout_handler():
    if cherrypy.request.cookie.get('Unauthorize') is not None:
        response = cherrypy.response
        response.headers['WWW-Authenticate'] = auth_digest.www_authenticate(
            realm=REALM,
            key=KEY,
            accept_charset=CHARSET
        )
        # delete the cookie that was used to mark the intention to logout
        response.cookie['Unauthorize'] = 1
        response.cookie['Unauthorize']['expires'] = 0
        raise cherrypy.HTTPError(
            401, 'You are not authorized to access that resource')


class App:
    @cherrypy.expose
    @cherrypy.tools.with_logout_handler()
    def index(self):
        return ('Welcome {}! Do you want to <a href="/logout">logout</a>?'
                .format(cherrypy.request.login))

    @cherrypy.expose
    def logout(self):
        """
        Set a cookie to give it a clue to the index method to
        remove the user credentials from the following requests.

        This will be handled by the tool `with_logout_handler`.
        """
        cherrypy.response.cookie['Unauthorize'] = 1
        raise cherrypy.HTTPRedirect("/")


def main():
    users = {
        'foo': 'bar'
    }
    cherrypy.quickstart(App(), config={
        '/': {
            'tools.auth_digest.on': True,
            'tools.auth_digest.realm': REALM,
            'tools.auth_digest.get_ha1': auth_digest.get_ha1_dict_plain(users),
            'tools.auth_digest.key': KEY,
            'tools.auth_digest.accept_charset': CHARSET
        },
    })

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Additionally, I'm not aware that the backend can configure any timeout on the client credentials for any type of native HTTP authentication, you can of course manage a session on your backend, based on `cherrypy.request.login`  and redirect to `/logout` if it already expired (like you could use the cherrypy sessions if you want to avoid managing the session yourself).